# Parametric Volume, volume analogue of parametric surface?

Tags: surfaces, volume, parametric, vector-fields, parametrization

Is it possible to have a parametric volume? Is it possible to have a parametric volume in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $V:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$, where $V$ is some function $V(x,y,z) = A(x,y,z)\hat{i}  + B(x,y,z)\hat{j} + C(x,y,z)\hat{k}$ ? In a parametric curve a curve is traced using the end point of the vector starting from the origin. In a parametric surface, there are two parameters which trace out the surface, so why not there be a parametric volume, where three parameters trace out the volume. I know it looks exactly like a vector field where every point in space gives you a unique vector, are the two perhaps somehow analogous, or is my entire thinking wrong and you cannot parametise a volume in this manor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. And if the mapping is regular in the sense that the Jacobian determinant of $A,B,C$ is non-zero, what you have is an alternative coordinate system in your region. You can also have a three-dimensional manifold in a space of higher dimension.

Comment: Yes i noticed that the infinitessimal volume element is given by volume of the parallelpiped $C \cdot (A\times B)$ which is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the parametric volume, is there any use for this other than calculating the volume of the surface in this coord system or integral of a scalar field over a region, like is there an analogue for vector fields?